# "Unrecognized lambda expression." when using Microsoft.Graph

Tags: vb.net, lambda, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to pull user data from Azure Active Directory.

I am adapting my code from the example application found at
https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-training-aspnetmvcapp/blob/main/Demos/03-add-msgraph/graph-tutorial/Helpers/GraphHelper.cs

My function currently looks like:

```
Public Async Function GetUserDetailsAsync(ByVal accessToken As String) As Task(Of CachedUser)
    Dim graphClient = New GraphServiceClient(New DelegateAuthenticationProvider(Function(requestMessage)
                                                                                    requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = New AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken)
                                                                                    Return Task.FromResult(0)
                                                                                End Function))

    Dim user = Await graphClient.Me.Request().Select(Function(u) New With {u.DisplayName}).GetAsync()

    Return New CachedUser With {
        .Avatar = String.Empty,
        .DisplayName = user.DisplayName,
        .Email = If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(user.Mail), user.UserPrincipalName, user.Mail)
    }
End Function
```

The problem is it is choking on the line with `GetAsync()`. I am receiving a exception with the message `Unrecognized lambda expression. Parameter name: selectExpression`

How am I supposed to write the Select? If this is a bug, does anyone have a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the issue, please refer to the following code

```
Dim graphClient = New GraphServiceClient(New DelegateAuthenticationProvider(Function(requestMessage)
                                                                                        requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = New AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken)
                                                                                        Return Task.CompletedTask
                                                                                    End Function))
        Dim user = Await graphClient.[Me].Request().[Select]("displayName").GetAsync()
        Console.WriteLine(user.DisplayName)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Comma separated works for multiple properties too, eg `graphClient.Me.Request().Select("DisplayName, Mail, UserPrincipalName")`